# Rust: Struct has a `packed(N)`-attribute (N > 1) but there is still padding between the fields

Tags: rust

TL;DR: I thought that the packed attribute in Rust always strips any padding between the fields but apparently this is only true for `packed(1)`.

I want my struct to represent the exact bytes in memory without any additional padding between fields but the struct also needs to be page-aligned. The compiler output isn't what I expect it to be in my code example. From the language reference [[0](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/type-layout.html)] I found, that `packed(N)` aligns the struct to a N-byte boundary. I expected that only the beginning of the struct is aligned while there is never padding between the fields. However, I found out that:

```rust
#[repr(C, packed(4096)]
struct Foo {
  first: u8,
  second: u32,
}

let foo = Foo { first: 0, second: 0 };
println!("foo is page-aligned: {}", &foo as *const _ as usize & 0xfff == 0);
println!("{:?}", &foo.first as *const _);
println!("{:?}", &foo.second as *const _);
println!("padding between fields: {}", &foo.second as *const _ as usize - &foo.first as *const _ as usize);
```

results in

```
foo is page-aligned: false
0x7ffc85be5eb8
0x7ffc85be5ebc
padding between fields: 4
```

Why is the struct not page-aligned and why is there padding between the fields? I found out that I can achieve what I want with

```rust
#[repr(align(4096))]
struct PageAligned<T>(T);

#[repr(C, packed)]
struct Foo {
    first: u8,
    second: u32,
}


let foo = Foo { first: 0, second: 0 };
let aligned_foo = PageAligned(Foo { first: 0, second: 0 });
```

it results in

```
foo is page-aligned: true
0x7ffd18c12000
0x7ffd18c12001
padding between fields: 1
```

but I think this is counter-intuitive. Is this how it is supposed to work? I'm on Rust stable 1.57.

Comment: [The Rust Reference on alignment modifiers](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/type-layout.html#the-alignment-modifiers): "*For `packed`, if the specified alignment is greater than the type's alignment without the `packed` modifier, then the alignment and layout is unaffected. The alignments of each field, for the purpose of positioning fields, is the smaller of the specified alignment and the alignment of the field's type.*"

Comment: thanks, I missed that. I still think it's counterintuitive.

Answer (score 0):

To meet the requirements with the available tools, your best option may be to construct a substitute for your `u32` field which naturally has an alignment of 1:

```rust
#[repr(C, align(4096))]
struct Foo {
  first: u8,
  second: [u8; 4],
}

impl Foo {
    fn second(&self) -> u32 {
        u32::from_ne_bytes(self.second)
    }
    
    fn set_second(&mut self, value: u32) {
        self.second = u32::to_ne_bytes(value);
    }
}
```

This struct's layout passes your tests.